# How do you install pub "zsh: command not found: pub" within Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just starting to learn Flutter. I come from an Angular background and used yarn, npm, which can be installed by brew. I am familiar with these package managers but not pub.

How do you install pub so the command works globally?

Looking for a command line to run.

I am on macOS Catalina

This is what I've tried so far:

I am trying to install the http package with:
`pub get`

however I get this error:
`zsh: command not found: pub`

I then tried to install pub with this line:
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub /usr/bin/pub`

And get this error:
`ln: /usr/bin/pub: Operation not permitted`

I then tried to install sudo by running:
`/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk1`

Then I get this error:
`Forced unmount of disk1 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted`

As I am going down this rabbit hole - I thought I would see if you guys had any suggestions!

Comment: What's operating system that you're running on? Did you have Flutter installed?

Comment: I updated the question with that info + more!

Comment: Did you try running `flutter doctor -v` to check for any missing tools?

Answer (score 8):

Use `flutter pub <command>` or `dart pub <command>` e.g. `flutter pub get` instead of trying to use `pub` directly.

---

Flutter maintains its own version of Dart internally and unless you've installed Dart explicitly `pub` will not be available in your `PATH`.

---

*Edit*

Standalone `pub` is deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try -> `flutter pub run build_runner build`